# I can't convert object to an array

Tags: arrays, laravel, object, shopping-cart

I am trying to make a shopping cart API route and I am stuck with this problem because when I am using this statement `$carts = \Cart::session($session)->getContent();`
 I get an object like this:

```
"cart": {
    "1": {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "Tort cu biscuiți",
        "price": 20,
        "quantity": "1",
        "attributes": {
            "image_path": "http://127.0.0.1:8000/storage/images/AkiGKJdxjKNtyoVI034RPL1drLsMntUxLfzqZplV.jpeg"
        },
        "conditions": []
    },
    "2": {
        "id": 2,
        "name": "Tort cu biscuiți",
        "price": 20,
        "quantity": 2,
        "attributes": {
            "image_path": "http://127.0.0.1:8000/storage/images/IkAhenLttHWaRD58hNZ460ykWCq7q1sih3vI9H5V.jpeg"
        },
        "conditions": []
    }
}
```

and I want to convet this to be array of objects. I tryied `$cart->toArray();` and didn't work, also I tiyed (array) $cart and I get this:

```
"cart": {
    "\u0000*\u0000items": {
        "1": {
            "id": 1,
            "name": "Tort cu biscuiți",
            "price": 20,
            "quantity": "1",
            "attributes": {
                "image_path": "http://127.0.0.1:8000/storage/images/AkiGKJdxjKNtyoVI034RPL1drLsMntUxLfzqZplV.jpeg"
            },
            "conditions": []
        },
        "2": {
            "id": 2,
            "name": "Tort cu biscuiți",
            "price": 20,
            "quantity": 2,
            "attributes": {
                "image_path": "http://127.0.0.1:8000/storage/images/IkAhenLttHWaRD58hNZ460ykWCq7q1sih3vI9H5V.jpeg"
            },
            "conditions": []
        }
    }
}
```

may I know what is the problem?

Comment: This Cart is your own custom object?  Won't you have to create the behaviour to ***tell*** it how-to become an array?

Comment: I use this package darryldecode/cart:~4.0 to create cart

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it manuel like this:

```
$carts = \Cart::session($session)->getContent();

if ($carts) {
    $cartsArray = json_decode($carts);
    foreach($cartsArray->cart as &$cart){
        $cart = (array) $cart;
    }
}

dd($cartsArray);
```

Comment: it throws me this error `Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalThrowableError: Cannot use object of type stdClass as array`

Comment: `foreach($cartsArray['cart'] as &$cart)`

Comment: Okey. Tell me what is return of this code : `echo get_class($cartsArray);` ?

Comment: it returns `stdClass`

Comment: Hmm okey then I did a change on my reply. Can you try this again?

Comment: now I have this error `Invalid argument supplied for foreach()`

Comment: what is `echo get_class($cartsArray->cart);` ?

Comment: `Undefined property: stdClass::$cart`

Comment: So I wanna make a question what are values and keys of this object? Can you share this `dd($cartsArray);` what return? Because I thought this stdClass has this items.

Comment: `{
    "cart": {
        "1": {
            "id": 1,
            "name": "Tort cu biscuiți",
            "price": 20,
            "quantity": "1",
            "attributes": {
                "image_path": "http://127.0.0.1:8000/storage/images/AkiGKJdxjKNtyoVI034RPL1drLsMntUxLfzqZplV.jpeg"
            },
            "conditions": []
        },
    }
}`

Comment: Hmm actually it seen like an json not an array. Are you sure this data return from `dd($cartsArray)` ?

Comment: {#269
  +"2": {#265
    +"id": 2
    +"name": "Tort cu biscuiți"
    +"price": 20
    +"quantity": 2
    +"attributes": {#259
      +"image_path": "http://127.0.0.1:8000/storage/images/IkAhenLttHWaRD58hNZ460ykWCq7q1sih3vI9H5V.jpeg"
    }
    +"conditions": []
}